# How to get all mshtml.IHTMLDivElement from IHTMLDocument2?

Tags: c#, .net, html, dom, mshtml

How to get all mshtml.IHTMLDivElement from IHTMLDocument2 ?

```
  private mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)WPFBrowser.Document;

  ???

  List<mshtml.IHTMLDivElement> allDivs = ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found solution. It works fantastic!**

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)MainBrowser.Document;

if (null != doc)
{
     foreach (IHTMLElement element in doc.all)
     {
           if (element.id == "wrapper")
           {
                 HTMLDivElement container = element as HTMLDivElement;

                 dynamic dd = container;

                 string result = dd.IHTMLElement_innerHTML;

                 // You get ANY member of HTMLDivElementClass

                  break;
             }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<mshtml.IHTMLDivElement> allDiv = doc
    .all.OfType<mshtml.IHTMLDivElement>()
    .ToList();
```